# How can I get favicon.ico to display for domain.com in IE8? (It shows up for www.domain.com)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, favicon

I'm not finding any uselful info via search.

I'm hosted at `discount.asp`.

The site in question is `42now.com`.  `42now.com` uses `favicon.ico` in Chrome and FF.

IE is not using it.  If you put `www.42now.com` in as the address, IE8 does display the icon.

Comment: I've noticed that it's now showing up.  I haven't changed on the site with respect to favicon.ico.  I guess it's some peculiarity with IE8?  It was at least a couple of hours before it showed up.  Maybe I rebooted?